# How to use oracle 'rowid' to sort using criteria builder

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api

Following illustrate my oracle 10g query to get sorted result between 311,320.But as social_id column is not unique i cannot use for sorting(as oracle doc says) so i have to use rowid with social_id combined as sort parameters

```
`select * from
  (select employee.*, rownum rnum
    from
     (select id,email,date,social_id
        from employee
           order by social_id, rowid) employee
    where rownum <= 320
   )
 where rnum >= 311;`
```

I have use Criteria api to build this query as follows.

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
    Root<Employee> root = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
    predicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("social_id").as(String.class), searchTerms + "%");
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("social_id")));

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    query.setFirstResult(331);
    query.setMaxResults(10);

    employee = query.getResultList();
```

So what i need is add that rowid to sorting parameters(to order by social_id and rowid both).Can any one help me to accomplish that task. Thanks

Comment: Any special reason to use rowid ?

Comment: if column has not unique data there is fault in return result set(same data returns).So in oracal doc it says to use rowid as second para for such instcances

Comment: can you show some sample data

Comment: This happens me to practically for further info read oracal 10g docs and you can read following doc https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results